# getting the original window back from numpy histogram

Tags: python, numpy

I am using numpy to construct a histogram as follows:

```
points = list()
# fill the list
uniques = set(points)
hist, bins = np.histogram(points, bins=len(uniques))
```

Now say I take an index in the histogram, say 4 i.e. `hist[4]` and `hist[4]` gives me the counts for that. Can I find out which actual value in my original data (`uniques`), it refers to?

Comment: What is in `bins[4]` ?

Comment: Yes, but not using histogram

Comment: @BlackBear counts.

Comment: @MadPhysicist what do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need histogram for what you are trying to do. [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) has `return_counts` and `return_inverse` flags to do exactly what you want. `return_inverse` returns the histogram of counts corresponding to each unique value. `return_inverse` returns the index into the unique values that tells you exactly where each item in the original data ends up.

You may also want to look into [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) and [`np.digitize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) as alternatives.